JAXBContext overwrites headelement with an element in its substitutionGroup in unmarschall()
I am using Jaxb 4.0 to deserialise an xml input file to a java object, and there is a mismatching between my two attributes extent and format: format takes the value of extent, whereas extent is null. They are both in a substitutionGroup where dc:format is a head element, as defined in http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/dcterms.xsd. An excerpt of the schema is as following:
   <xs:element name="format" substitutionGroup="dc:format"/>
   <xs:element name="extent" substitutionGroup="format"/>
   <xs:element name="medium" substitutionGroup="format"/>


Both of the attributes are defined as child elements of a Source element as in the schema schema.xsd below:
<xs:element name="Source" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="dc:format"> </xs:element> 

        <xs:element ref="dcterms:extent"></xs:element>
                ...
        All other attributes are mapped correctly.
                ...
     </xs:sequence>                 
</xs:element>

I've tried supposedly all possible solutions out there in StackOverflow, but it did not work, to name a few known solutions: the annotation of the generated classes from the dcterms.xsd schemas contains substitutionHeadNamespace and substitutionHeadName, the jaxbcontext is correctly created, and both of the following approaches work the same way:
JAXBContext context;
context = JAXBContext.newInstance(
     com.mycompany.model.dcterms.ObjectFactory.class,
     com.mycompany.model.schmema.ObjectFactory.class
);
or 
context = JAXBContext.newInstance(
       "com.mycompany.model.dcterms:com.mycompany.model.schema"
);

I spent several days to debug the source code of jaxb, and what I found out is that whenever an entry is created for "format", it would overwrite all other entries of its substitionGroup elements, so that all of the elements in format substitionGroup will be registered with a fieldName "format". When an element in that group is mapped, in this case it is extent, the unmarshaller will think that it is actually a format and in my case format is mapped before extent, the value of format is overwritten by extent's value.
I want to ask whether or not this phenomenon is what a JAXBContext supposes to do or is there any way to solve the problem I am having without changing the schema.xsd.
Thank you for reading this question, I highly appreciate any help.
